# Increasing Perfomance in nested fragments and room

Tags: java, android, database, fragment

I making app for android, this image shwowe, what i have now:

[image]

So i have MainActivity, with FrameLayout and Toolbar. (in some fragments i need to hide toolbar, in some change it's name)

In MainActivity i have FrameLayout.

The app working like this: i have server, where i get data. I made repository + viewmodel + livedata (like in google codelabs), and using socket.io for connecting with server.

For example i have 2 fragments to show some information, so how it works:

Firstly user get to FragmentMain (code below):

Method in MainActivity to setFragments

```
protected void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment);
    t.commit();
}
```

also i'm using this code to connect with database and show actual data to user via google advices (i mean architectural components)

so in onCreate i'm calling

```
 appUpdateViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AppUpdateViewModel.class);

 fragmentMain = new FragmentMain();

 setFragment(fragmentMain);
```

in FragmentMain i'm following next steps to show nested fragment (components or system

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ...
    ((MainActivityPfff)getActivity()).setTextTabBar(getString(R.string.fragment_main_toolbar));

    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterPagerMain(getActivity(),getFragmentManager()));
    ...
}
```

This code for AdapterPagerMain

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return new FragmentComponents();
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return new SystemFragment();
    } else {
        return new SystemFragment(); //notUsing
    }
}
```

And this code for FragmentComponents (the ComponentsFragment structure same, but showing another data)

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    appUpdateViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AppUpdateViewModel.class);
    appUpdateViewModel.getAllAppUpdates().observe(this, new Observer<List<AppUpdate>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<AppUpdate> appUpdates) {
            adapterUpdates.setUpdates(appUpdates);
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

When i'm showing FragmentMain i can click on the button and go to new Fragment (for example FragmentAboutApp), so i'm doing it like that:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setFragment(new FragmentAboutApp());
        }
```

So, first problem that i get - it when i'm clicking on button in FragmentAboutApp, which showing FragmentMain, i'm getting FragmentMain, but without any content (in FragmentComponents and FragmentSystem i have recyclerViews, that getting info from database)

Also i dont know is right way to get actual data (i mean create new appViewModels in all fragment and observe on data). I'm wondering about memory leaking

And also i'm wondering about using nested fragments. Should i recreate it or not? I need to increase perfomance to max level. Or maybe i need to delete old instance of Fragments when going to new? (Please show code, how i can do it)

Last question - i'm downloading from server big json file with some information:

-different parts of this information i use in differents fragments (but i'm downloading only one file)

So, now i connect to server in MainActivity, and getting actual json in MainActivity lifecycle. Fragments are just observing on this database and than it changes they showing actual info

Thank you!